# SDL_KEYUP triggered when key is still down

Tags: c++, sdl, sdl-2

I am using SDL2 in C++ to create a sprite. However, the SDL_KEYUP is constantly triggered when I am pressing the key.

```
        void update() override {
            if(Game::event.type == SDL_KEYDOWN) {
                switch(Game::event.key.keysym.sym) {
                    case SDLK_z:
                        cout << "key down" << endl;
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;                    
                }
            }
            if(Game::event.type == SDL_KEYUP) {
                switch(Game::event.key.keysym.sym) {
                    case SDLK_z:
                        cout << "Key up" << endl;
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;                    
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a feature, not a bug. If you hold a key for half a second or so, SDL will start to generate "fake" key-down & key-up events.

This is used primarily for text editing, but is mostly useless otherwise.

Ignore all keyboard events that have `event.key.repeat != 0`.

---

Also, if you're writing a game, you might want to use scancodes instead of keycodes (e.g. `event.key.keysym.scancode == SDL_SCANCODE_A` instead of `event.key.keysym.sym == SDLK_a`).

Keycodes depend on the current layout, and scancodes don't. Scancodes represent physical key locations. The diffence is noticeable if you use a non-QWERTY layout. (E.g. `SDLK_z` is always bound to the key that has `Z` printed on it, while `SDL_SCANCODE_W` is bound to `W` on QWERTY and `Z` on AZERTY.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am using GetKeyboardState() now, which works well.